# Was Hagrid able to cast a Patronus, and if so what was its form?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid, patronus-charm

Hagrid is not shown casting a Patronus anywhere in the series, but still he was an Order member, and Order members usually communicate by means of a Patronus. Is there any indication that Hagrid was able to cast a Patronus, and if so, what was its form?

Comment: Hagrid probably is not skilled enough to cast a patronus, he also only has a broken wand, but it would be a dragon for sure.

Comment: @Himarm There's no 'probably' about it. This question isn't primarily opinion-based; there's a canon answer for heaven's sake!

Comment: Welcome to the SciFi/Fantasy Stack Exchange! I have edited your question to remove the request for speculation, as we generally don't allow speculative/opinionated questions on this site. Please let me know if you have any issues with my changes.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I was just doing the same when your edit loaded! You did that damn apostrophe wrong again though :-)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield No issues!

Comment: @randal'thor As an aside, you mean the apostrophe in "it's"? I thought that was the correct form?

Comment: @Astant it is its for possessive form of it, and it is it's for the contraction it is.

Comment: @Himarm Ohh thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hagrid **could not produce a Patronus**.

Word-of-JKR, discussed [here](http://time.com/4014510/harry-potter-jk-rowling-hagrid/) and [here](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/news/jk-rowling-reveals-harry-potter-character-hagrid-could-not-produce-a-patronus-10475057.html), originally on Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/634666242943655936):

> Hagrid couldn't produce a Patronus. It's a very difficult spell.

Since Hagrid was expelled before completing his studies at Hogwarts, it makes sense that - like many grown-up witches and wizards, in fact - he never learnt the difficult Patronus Charm. Some have also speculated that due to his unhappy childhood, he didn't have enough happy memories to draw on in order to cast it.

Comment: "Some have also speculated that due to his unhappy childhood, he didn't have enough happy memories to draw on in order to cast it." I don't know about that. Snape made one just fine, and his upbringing was depressing as hell.

Comment: @TenthJustice Yeah, I don't agree with that either. Just thought I'd put it out there though.

Comment: @TenthJustice Snape’s a sourpuss git to begin with. ‘Happy thoughts’ probably means something slightly different to him, like a fantasy about a cauldron of Boil-Ballooning potion blowing up in Neville or Hermione’s face…

Comment: Harry's childhood also wasn't exactly full of glitter and puppies, but he was able to produce a full bodied Patronus

Comment: I suspect Hagrid simply wasn't a powerful/skillful enough wizard to cast it, particularly since JKR implies that in her tweet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That, or his memories with/of Lily :'(

Comment: @TenthJustice, not that I support that as being the ground for Hagrid not being able to cast a Patronus, but Harry's learning of the spell shows that the memory does not have to be true. So Snape's powerful love and shared moments, would probably give him strength enough.